# How to get the GPU architecture of a device?

Tags: cuda

cudaGetDeviceProperties has attributes for getting the compute capability (major.minor), but, how do we get the GPU architecture (sm_**) to feed into the compilation for a device?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, that's what the major & minor properties encode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- sm_10 is a compute capability 1.0 device
- sm_11 is a compute capability 1.1 device
- sm_12 is a compute capability 1.2 device
- sm_13 is a compute capability 1.3 device
- sm_20 is a compute capability 2.0 device
- sm_21 is a compute capability 2.1 device
- sm_30 is a compute capability 3.0 device
- sm_32 is a compute capability 3.2 device
- sm_35 is a compute capability 3.5 device
- sm_37 is a compute capability 3.7 device
- sm_50 is a compute capability 5.0 device
- sm_52 is a compute capability 5.2 device
- sm_53 is a compute capability 5.3 device
- sm_60 is a compute capability 6.0 device
- sm_61 is a compute capability 6.1 device
- sm_62 is a compute capability 6.2 device

sm_XY corresponds to "physical" or "real" architecture

compute_ZW  corresponds to ["virtual" architecture](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#virtual-architectures)

not all sm_XY have a corresponding compute_XY

for example, there is no compute_21 (virtual) architecture

Answer (score -1):

simplest way

if you are using cuda 7.x , using nvcc flags like below to gain compatibility

```
-arch=sm_30 \
-gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
-gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52
```

if you are using cuda 8.x, set the flags like below:

```
-arch=sm_30 \
-gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
-gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
-gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
-gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
-gencode=arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 \
```